# Bootstrap-switch state

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm hoping someone that uses bootstrap-switch can explain this to me.

If I have a bootstrap-switch element, say #test... if I do `$('#test').val()` then I always get the same result irrespective of the state of the bootstrap-switch?

So I need to somehow call the state of the object, in which case I'll get true or false.

Surely there's a way to use `val()` to get the selected value - at the end of the day it's just a checkbox. How do I do it though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not user of bootstrap-switch but after going to it's demo page I've noticed that there is an checkbox input. You can read the state by reading checkbox state:

```
// switch to OFF
$('.bootstrap-switch-container input').prop('checked')
// false

// switch to ON
$('.bootstrap-switch-container input').prop('checked')
// true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this too:

```
// switch to OFF
$('.bootstrap-switch-container input').bootstrapSwitch();
// false

// switch to ON
$('.bootstrap-switch-container input').bootstrapSwitch();
// true
```